# Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Textbox'?

Tags: vb.net

My form named form2.vb has this code.

```
Private Sub ADDRESS_TICKETDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles ADDRESS_TICKETDataGridView.CellDoubleClick
        Dim value As String = ADDRESS_TICKETDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString()
        If e.ColumnIndex = e.ColumnIndex Then
            Search.Show()
            Search.TextBox1 = value



        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

But on the error gives me that Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.
I want to fix this issue essentially what I want is to get the value from a datagridview and input it on another form that has a textbox. Could it be done or am I doing something wrong. Please help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Search.TextBox1 = value
```

You just tried to assign the `TextBox1` variable to hold a string instead of a textbox.

That doesn't make any sense.

Instead, you want to set the text being displayed in the textbox, by setting its `Text` property.

Comment: I am sorry but I am learning as I am adapting to this language. But I done that before it work like form2.Textbox = "Value" like that it works.

Comment: @NOE2270667: Unless you define a property named `Textbox` of type `String` in your form2, this will never work.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking VBA

Comment: @NOE2270667: Yes; I thought so.  VBA has default properties, which allow you to do that (`TextBox`'s default property is `Text`).  I don't think that feature was a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just for information (and to add to my comment on Slacks's answer), there is a way to approach this behaviour, using operators overloading.  (Code is in C#, but I guess it's easily translatable in VB.Net)

Just create a class inheriting from `TextBox` like this:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static implicit operator string(MyTextBox t)
    {
        return t.Text;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyTextBox(string s)
    {
        MyTextBox tb = new MyTextBox();
        tb.Text = s;
        return tb;
    }

    public static MyTextBox operator +(MyTextBox tb1, MyTextBox tb2)
    {
        tb1.Text += tb2.Text;
        return tb1;
    }
}
```

And then you'll be able to do things like this:

```
MyTextBox tb = new MyTextBox();
tb.Text = "Hello ";
tb += "World";
```

The content of your textbox will then be `Hello World`

I tried making it work with `tb = "test"`, but haven't succeeded.